# Nuget client 3.0 support

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xamarin

I am writing xamarin app which will work on windows and OS X (using profile 7)
I am trying to add the nuget system.xml.xpath

However, it gives me the below error-
Adding System.Xml.XPath...
The 'System.Xml.XPath 4.0.0' package requires NuGet client version '3.0' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.7.0'.

I have two question-
1.
how soon will xamarin start supporting nugget client 3.0 or above?
2.
how can i resolve my specific problem?

Comment: You need to upgrade to NuGet 3.0, see [Installing NuGet](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/installing-nuget)..

Answer (score 1):

On OS-X you can:

```
sudo nuget update -self
```

Note: sudo is required as this will update the nuget.exe within the Mono Framework

```
>nuget
NuGet Version: 3.4.4.1321
```

There is a nuget3 branch of Xamarin Studio 6.1 but I have not seen when that will go into an public alpha release...

Answer (score 0):

You do not say what development environment you are using. The error message suggest you are using Xamarin Studio, since Visual Studio already supports NuGet 3.

There is a preview branch of Xamarin Studio 6.1 which does support NuGet 3, this is currently available on the alpha channel in Xamarin Studio.

However whilst using Xamarin Studio 6.1 will allow you to do is add the System.Xml.XPath NuGet package to your project you will still not be able to use anything from that NuGet package currently since there are no assemblies in it for the Xamarin frameworks and currently the Xamarin build tools will not add the correct assembly references for you at compile time.